# в Debug area не печатается вывод функции print

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть код одного файла:

```
 //
//  Constants.swift
//  pixel-city
//
//  Created by apple on 01.02.2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 apple. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

let apiKey = "bca9713a70298e4376337d7a5876fb8b"

func flickrUrl(forApiKey key: String, withAnnotation annotation:               
DroppablePin, andNumberOfPhotos number: Int) -> String {
let url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?     
method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=\(apiKey)&lat=\. 
(annotation.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\.  
(annotation.coordinate.longitude)&radius=2&radius_units=km&per_page=\.   
(number)&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
print(url)
return url
}
```

И кусок кода второго файла. Особо прошу обратить внимание на последнюю строку:

```
let touchPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)
    let touchCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

    let annotation = DroppablePin(coordinate: touchCoordinate, identifier: "droppablePin")
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print(flickrUrl(forApiKey: apiKey, withAnnotation: annotation, andNumberOfPhotos: 40))
```

Пока ничего не выводится в поле Debug area:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема!

Comment: Делегат назначен?

Comment: Скажите, а где это поле "Filter"?? я недавно изучаю ios разработку поэтому не знаю где это находится

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, не заполнено ли поле Filter. Если заполнено, то консоль отобразит только то, что содержит его значение.